# jquery-ui 1.10.2 tabs selecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-tabs

Using jquery-ui 1.10.2, I am unable to *select* a tab as usual.  I am using `$('.selector').tabs('select', '.selector');` as with earlier versions of jquery-ui.

What is the replacement for this functionality in the latest version of jquery-ui.

I have created a jsFiddle test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgergen/5RMaN/37/). (http://jsfiddle.net/jgergen/5RMaN/37/).

Thank you,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the latest version of jquery-ui - 'select' is not longer available.
To select a tab, you must use the options.  The following code will select a tab.

```
// tabs are 0 based indexed
$('#tSheet').tabs('options', 'active', 1);
// will select the second tab.
```

Still have not found a way to get the tab index without a lot of DOM navigation.
it would be nice to have something like this:  `$('#tSheet').tabs('find', '.selector');`

Thank you all for your help.
Jim

Comment: if you want to target based on href you could try this way `$('#tSheet').tabs("option", "active", $('[href=#page-2]').closest('li').index())`

Answer (score 1):

Move `$('#tSheet').tabs();` to the bottom after appending the elements.

```
$('#tSheet ul').append('<li><a href="#page-1">One</a></li>');
$('#tSheet ul').append('<li><a href="#page-2">Two</a></li>');
$('#tSheet ul').append('<li><a href="#page-3">Three</a></li>');

$('#tSheet').append('<div id="page-1">Page One Text</div>');
$('#tSheet').append('<div id="page-2">Page Two Text</div>');
$('#tSheet').append('<div id="page-3">Page Three Text</div>');
$('#tSheet').tabs();
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XTksJ/)

For dynamic tabs use this syntax `$('#tSheet').tabs("option", "active", 2);`

Comment: and remove this lines `$('#tSheet').tabs('refresh');
    $('#tSheet').tabs('select', '#page-1');`

Comment: That may work for static tabs.  Does not for dynamic tabs.  Thank you.